# I can't get full html code when souping a dynamic table using Beautiful Soup/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having troubles souping a dynamic table with Beautiful soup/Selenium

When I run the code, I can´t get the entire html code in my notebook.

The tags I am interested with are under the tag 'frameset' which I should somehow "open". How could I do this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Administrador/Documents/chromedriver')
main_url = 'https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html'
driver.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
soup

output : <html><head></head><frameset border="0" cols="*" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" id="fset" rows="190,*">
<frame name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" src="Index.html"/>
<frame align="center" name="mainFrame" src="about:blank"/>
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Depending on what you plan on doing with the data, you likely don’t even need BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Also, I’m willing to bet that this is simply a case of the output in the notebook getting cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the driver's frame and store the value:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("topFrame"))
frame_source = driver.page_source
```

The frame_source variable should store the iframe's source code. I checked the website, and the iframe's name is 'topFrame'.

Comment: What would this change, what is the issue?

Comment: The lxml parser is not imported by default with BeautifulSoup. OP does not specify exactly what the issue is, so the answer assumes he is getting a crash. Substituting lxml with html.parser works as html.parser is imported by default.

Comment: Thank you for answering!! The problem is that I can´t access the full html code because it is a dynamic table. The tags I am interested with are under the tag frameset but I cant have access to them when souping. Any thought on how could I access them?

Comment: I updated my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @EmilioChambouleyron What are you trying to do with that page?

Comment: @zenalc Yes, exactly that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AMC I want to extract all the data from that table and make a dataframe

Comment: Would you mind picking the answer as a solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EmilioChambouleyron Yeah, Selenium should be much more convenient. Remember that Pandas has a [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) function!